# Does WPF FrameworkElement.Parent property raise any sort of property changed event?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, frameworkelement

I would like to write a new FrameworkElement that registers for events on its visual parent. That means it needs to know when it is attached and detached from the visual tree. The FrameworkElement.Parent tells the current Parent. That would work great if I could get any sort of event from it, but it does not seem to support any sort of event generation. The property doesn't call property changed notification, it isn't virtual and it isn't a DependencyProperty.

Does anyone know how a control can register for changes to its own Parent property?

Comment: Did you have a look at the Loaded and Unloaded events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FrameworkElement.Loaded` (`LoadedEvent`) and `FrameworkElement.Unloaded` (`UnloadedEvent`) appear to be the right places to add and remove listeners for the framework parent.